# I can't load more than 40 UITableViewCells in my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, pagination

I am parsing XML that gets the first 25 items in my MySQL database using PHP - LIMIT and GET. When I click on the "Load More" cell that I append to the bottom of my tableview, it successfully gets the next 25 items, but only loads the first 40 and leaves off the last 10. Each time I click on the "Load more" cell it add 25 to my range (ie 0-25,25-50), but it seems that my range caps at 65 and the display caps at 40.

Here is my load more function thats not working:

```
-(void) getNewRange{
    int currentRange = [allItems count];
    int newRange = currentRange + 25;

    if(newRange > [xmlParser total]){
        NSLog(@"evaluating as greater than the total, which is 837");
        newRange = [xmlParser total];
    }

    NSString *range = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"?range=%d&range2=%d",currentRange,newRange];
    NSString *newUrl =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/fetchAllTitles.php%@",range];

    XMLParser *tempParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:newUrl];
    [allItems addObjectsFromArray:[tempParser people]];
    NSMutableArray *newCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:25];

    for(int i=currentRange;i<newRange;i++){
        NSLog(@"%d",i);
         NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [newCells addObject:indexpath];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",newUrl);

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I'm getting closer, but I get this new error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableView isn't a class to contain your data, and you shouldn't try to directly micromanage what cells it displays.  As another poster stated, read up on how to use it.  What you should do is:

```
-(void)loadNewData
{
    NSIndexPath *index;
    XMLParser *tempParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:newUrl];
    NSArray *people=[tempParser people];
    for(id *person in people)
    {
        [self.dataArray addObject:person];
        indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.dataArray indexForObject:person] inSection:0];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{ 
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [AnArray count];//use whatever array stores your data
}


//If you've subclassed the cell, adjust appropriately.
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    //Customize the cell
    return cell;
}
```

The table view will take care of all the logic involved in displaying the cells, if you let it.  This way, you only have a limited number of cells taking up memory at any given time, and you don't have to handle that -- the table view automagically handles reusing the cells, and knowing how many are needed as a buffer before / after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would up vote it, but i dont have enough points. I edited my original post, with the 'insertRowsAtIndexPaths', but i dont think i understand where i get the new indexpaths from or how to present it in an array. whenever i make an array with '[NSNumber numberWithInt:counter]' i get an error. Thanks again. BTW it doesnt seem like the array is growing in length at all, i still get 40 every time and they are the same items.

Comment: @rcpilot51 You may want to go in and clean up your question, the code (as presented) is invalid, with commands not placed in actual function calls (and bad tabulation).

Comment: I cleaned up my post. please check out the error that im getting now...thanks

Comment: @rcpilotp51 A quick google search suggests that there's an inconsistency between the number of rows you're adding, and the number of rows that you're reporting in the datasource rows in section call.  Looking at your data, I suspect that you aren't looping over your parser code, so it only calls (and adds new rows) once (?) and then you manually tell the table to add many more rows.

Comment: Woops, you're using add objects, not add object.  If I were you, I'd probably put that value into a temporary array, and use it's count to indicate where the rows are at.

Comment: no, I was unable to work on it over the weekend. I'll try tonight. Btw I'm using add object and making a temp array as you can see above. I'll let you know tonight. Thanks

Comment: @rcpilotp51 Well, looking at it, I'd probably do a forin loop over the values you get from the temporary parser, and add each resulting value independently to the array.  That way, your ads are tied directly to the values being added.

Comment: is that what im doing here:
'for(int i=currentRange;i<newRange;i++){         NSLog(@"%d",i);          NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];         [newCells addObject:indexpath];     } '

Comment: @rcpilotp51 No, it's not.  You're assuming you're getting 25 new rows, but you never check that's how many the XML parser gives you.

Comment: I guess that's my problem, and brings me back to my original question. How do I get the parser to get more than 40 items total. Right now I'm getting 25 then when I call the function again 'NSlog' prints out 15 - giving me a total of 40 no matter what. Even though there is a total of over 800 records.

Comment: @rcpilotp51 That's a totally different question than what you've been asking.  If you're only getting a total of 40 out of the parser, your problem isn't with the UITableView at all!  Without knowing what library your using (I don't think that's an apple default one, as they all start with NS, UI, CA, and the like), there's little to nothing I can do to help you.

Comment: i've made an 'xmlParser' class using 'NSXMLParser' with the 'didStartElement' and 'didEndElement' methods... it parses through and adds info into a CellInfo class with a bunch of variables, depending on the node's info. the parser is allocated in the 'viewDidLoad' of my tableview View as such 'xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://localhost/fetchAllTitles.php"];' does that help?

Comment: I'm shocked that 'localhost' is working AT ALL, to be honest.  Past that, I'm not really sure.  Don't use those classes much (ever).  I suspect you should mark this problem solved (You've fixed the UITableView issues) and open a new question based on your new problem (the parser stuff).

Comment: its funny. I'm looking at this years later. What a Noob I was. Live and learn. right?

Comment: @rcpilotp51 I think we've all been there.  I don't even want to THINK about how many of my early questions would feel noobish if I dared look at them.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on how you can **Reuse your table view's cells**.

Your data does not need to be 'owned' by the cell.

Answer (score 2):

you should not set numberOfRowsInSection inside your method. The number of rows should get returned from the tableView's datasource method `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`. Just return `[allItems count]` there.